# Como obter uma lista com todas as perguntas e alternativas moodle?

Tags: json, api, moodle

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android com java para a plataforma moodle, e eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que retorne uma lista com a pergunta do quiz e as alternativas. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
{ "question": "1 + 1 vale:", alternatives":[2,3,10,8] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue o SQL para gerar a lista de perguntas e alternativas de respostas:

```
SELECT q.id, q.questiontext as questão, q.qtype as tipo, qa.answer as alternativas
FROM mdl_question q
INNER JOIN mdl_question_answers qa on qa.question = q.id
WHERE q.id = ? -- Id do questionário(quiz)
```